# Why adding index to django model slowed the exectuion time?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, optimization

I've added the index to my django model in order to make the queries on it a little bit faster but the execution time actually went up:

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from django.db import models


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
    population = models.IntegerField()
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="name")

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['slug'])]
```

And I've used this function to calculate execution time for my CBV:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    start_time = timezone.now()
    response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    end_time = timezone.now()
    execution_time = (end_time - start_time).total_seconds() * 1000
    print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} ms")
    return response
```

Before adding `indexes` to `Meta` class the execution time on `City.objects.all()` in my CBV was:

```
Execution time: 190.413 ms
```

But after adding it it became:

```
Execution time: 200.201 ms
```

Is there any idea why that happens? Perhaps it is unadvisable to use indexes on `slug` fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was because `.all()` doesn't use the `slug` field on its query so adding the field actually proved not beneficial but rather redundant in this case.